# Is Argon2 better than salted hashing algorithm?

Tags: hash, passwords, password-encryption, saltedhash, argon2-ffi

I already know that slow-hashing functions are good for storing passwords as it is very time consuming to crack them. And we know that Argon2 is a slow algorithm, and not only that, but Argon2 consumes a lot of memory as well. A webmaster would just require the resources only once upon login attempt or password creation, where as the attacker/hacker will require such resources per each and every single try. This makes Argon2 somewhat better than secure hashing algorithms.

But I want deep insights into my original question that, is Argon2 better than salted hashing algorithm?

Comment: Argon2 **is** is salted hashing algorithm (and iterated, and designed to mitigate hardware advantage, and lots of other good things).

Answer (score 0):

Argon2 is a salted hashing algorithm.